# Yocto recipe to install binaries generated from cmake

Tags: cmake, yocto, recipe, petalinux

I am new to Yocto and cmake. After looking and searching on internet I was able to make my own recipe and  was able to successfully compile the code using cmake from Yocto recipe.
But the binary compiled and generated is in the build folder where the code source files reside. How do I copy over the binaries from the build folder to the custom file system path when the image is generated using Yocto.

My .bb file currently looks like this:

```
#
# This file is the pscode recipe.
#

SUMMARY = "Simple test application"
SECTION = "PETALINUX/apps"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://src/*     \
           file://include/* \
           file://CMakeLists.txt\
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_configure() {
    cmake ../
}

inherit pkgconfig cmake

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}/home/first
         cp -r ${WORKDIR} ${D}/home/first
         #install -m 0755 ${S} ${D}/home/first
}


FILES_${PN} += "/home/first"
```

This runs into error

```
cp: cannot copy a directory <path-to-the-test-folder-in-temp> into itself, <path-to-the-test-folder-in-temp/image/home/first>
```

Can I someone please guide me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I haven't setup a yocto package in a while, but if your cmake follows standard practices, you shouldn't have to provide `do_configure` or `do_install`.

Comment: @StephenNewell ok removing do_configure works... but removing do_install throws me another error  `ERROR: Execution of <<path-to-the-test-folder-in-temp>/run.do_install.17675 failed with exit code1:
ninja: error: unknown target 'install'
`

Comment: Does your cmake try to install anything?

Comment: No it does not... it just generates the binaries in the build folder

Comment: Then I'd suggest you get your cmake project working on its own, including proper installation.  After that, the minimal recipe should work without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments suggested:

```
SUMMARY = "Simple test application"
SECTION = "PETALINUX/apps"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://src/*     \
           file://include/* \
           file://CMakeLists.txt \
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit pkgconfig cmake
```

If the CMakeLists.txt uses the install command then bitbake will do the install for you and you won't need to define you own do_install. see [cmake-documentation-install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/install.html) for details. Here the example for binaries:

```
install(TARGETS <your cmake target> DESTINATION bin)
```

From cmake install documentation:

> If a full path (with a leading slash or drive letter) is given it is
> used directly. If a relative path is given it is interpreted relative
> to the value of the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX variable.

Comment: install(TARGETS <your cmake target> DESTINATION bin) always installs in the bin directory can I change the destination folder? Thanks

Comment: yes you can change the directory if you replace bin with lib it will installs your files at /usr/lib.

Comment: Currently I make a build directory locally do cmake and it installs it to ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build but with petalinux-build it does not create a build folder and tries to install the binaries at /usr/bin folder which I do not want. How can I add the binaries and all the necessary outputs to a custom folder...for example /home/my_dir/app/? I do not mind it this path contains build folder I can package the whole contents by changing the yocto recipe to copy everything in the petalinux image.

Comment: I added following lines to make a build folder in cmake but it does not work. ` file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
install (DIRECTORY DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)`